# My classmate and I are having an issue understanding the question being asked as folllows:

Tags: python, math

The math module includes a POW function that raises a number to a given power. The first argument is the number, and the second is the exponent. Write the code segment that imports this function and calls it to print the values of 82 and 54.

One of us is thinking it goes:

```
print(pow(8,2),pow(5,4))
```

The other person is thinking:

```
print(pow(82,1))
print(pow(54,1))
```

Can you please help us out. We are both reading the question differently. Thanks

Comment: You should probably be asking your teacher regarding this question.

Comment: Have you tried running both thoughts on the Python shell? One of them prints `64 625`. I do think it is a weird question just to ask for a certain value to be printed though.

Comment: Well that's quite ambiguous. Both are technically right. But my guess is that you're supposed to use `pow` with a power of a number to get to 82 and do the same for 54. 54 to the power of 1 and 82 to the power of 1 is an unnecessary use of `pow`

Comment: Ive run them both. One thinks the result should end up being 82 and 54 and the other thinks the result should be the result of 8 to the power of 2 and 5 to the power of 4.

Comment: The first "thinking" makes no sense, unless it was written 8² and 5⁴, and it is poorly worded otherwise.  82 and 54 aren't nice powers of anything.

Comment: Really strange task, if you had to find all pairs (number,exponent) that  gives 82 and 54 as the result ot would make more sense for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check here,

I could not paste it in the comments.

[Fundamentals of Python](https://books.google.com.om/books?id=VtfM3YGW5jYC&pg=PA70&lpg=PA70&dq=The%20math%20module%20includes%20a%20POW%20function%20that%20raises%20a%20number%20to%20a%20given%20power.%20The%20first%20argument%20is%20the%20number,%20and%20the%20second%20is%20the%20exponent.%20Write%20the%20code%20segment%20that%20imports%20this%20function%20and%20calls%20it%20to%20print%20the%20values%20of%2082%20and%2054&source=bl&ots=9tZI6oLrmN&sig=ACfU3U2pYLGR1h2GmloO86tePb2EVscy1Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwig6-nYh-bnAhVBtIsKHYj0AGwQ6AEwA3oECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=The%20math%20module%20includes%20a%20POW%20function%20that%20raises%20a%20number%20to%20a%20given%20power.%20The%20first%20argument%20is%20the%20number%2C%20and%20the%20second%20is%20the%20exponent.%20Write%20the%20code%20segment%20that%20imports%20this%20function%20and%20calls%20it%20to%20print%20the%20values%20of%2082%20and%2054&f=false)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import pow

print(pow(82, 54))
```